# Index error: string index out of range python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to write a program that prints out the longest substring in alphabetical order in a string. 
Here is my code:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
n = 0
longest = "a"

while n < len(s):
    x = n
    for i in s:
       if s[x + 1] >= s[x]:
          x += 1
       else:
          break

   sub_string = (s[n:x+1])
   if len(sub_string) > len(longest):
   longest = sub_string
   n += 1
```

print ("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + longest)

Because I'm incrementing 'x' at every iteration and as a result, the index soon gets out of range. Just wondering if there's a way i could get around this.
Thanks.

Comment: I see some broken indentation.

Comment: Broken indentation, you never increment the value of n, it will be an infinite loop unless it hits your break statement

Comment: Thanks. Missed the indentation while formating the code here. But that doesn't solve my problem yet. Thanks though.

Comment: `for` is not aligned with `sub_string` indentation issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
n = 0
longest = "a"
while n < len(s):
    x = n
    for i in s:
        if x+1<len(s) and s[x + 1] >= s[x]:
            x += 1
        else:
            break
    sub_string = (s[n:x+1])
    if len(sub_string) > len(longest):
        longest = sub_string
    n += 1
print(longest)
```

EDIT: when `n = len(s)-1` s[x+1] will point to nth char of s, which is invalid. So you needed an additional condition `x+1<len(s)` to keep that in check.

Comment: that was awsome man. You wouldn't believe the hours I have spent trying to fix this. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @jean I explained why his code wasn't working in the comments. Anyways I will make an edit. Thanks for pointing.